# My dataflow-template does not start steps before BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a code created with apache-beam, which reads a csv file and inserts it into BigQuery. In the pipeline I execute three steps (apply): 1. read csv, 2. transform text to TableRow, and 3. insert into BigQuery (`BigQueryIO.writeTableRow()`)

I create the template, but when I'm going to execute it (with dataflow-runner) it only executes the BigQuery step. Do not start the steps of reading csv or transforming to TableRow.

What could be happening?

[-- This is the failed execution --](http://www.danielgomez.cl/imagen_dataflow.png)

I tried commenting the BigQuery block (apply), and there it executes the previous steps. I also tried generating a pipeline in parallel, and also runs it. The problem arises when I link the pipeline to the step (apply) of BigQuery.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

     String sourceFilePath = "gs://dgomez_test/input.csv";
     String tempLocationPath = "gs://dgomez_test/tmp";

     PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
     options.setTempLocation(tempLocationPath);
     options.setJobName("csvtobq");
     Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

     p.apply("read csv", TextIO.read().from(sourceFilePath))
      .apply("string to tablerow", ParDo.of(new FormatForBigquery()));
      .apply("write to bigquery",
           BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(TABLE)
               .withSchema(FormatForBigquery.getSchema())
               .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
               .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));

     p.run();
}
```

Comment: check the stack driver logs, I had similar cases, sometimes there are errors, and they are shown only in stack driver, and not in the logs section in data flow.

Comment: It is possible that the Dataflow UI only had a delay to report the proper status of the steps. You can confirm if the pipeline read and wrote the rows by looking at the BigQuery table. If this is not the case, please share the errors you observe in the steps, you can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#Workflow) to look at the logs.

Comment: Is the data properly written? If the data is properly written, it's impossible that it skipped the first two steps